# Count the number of points closer than a given distance

Tags: algorithm, scala, coordinates, distance, points

I'm developing a project that given a set of coordinates (lat and longitude) needs to find all the points that are closer than a given distance (in Km).

I have working implementation that iterates over each point and for each point iterates over all the other points. This is O(n^2). I'd like to know what approach could I follow to improve this, having in mind that I don't want the closest point but the ones that are closer than x Km (also I'd like to be able to do the opposite, finding all the points that are further away than x Km).

If you could provide some ideas and algorithms it would be nice. Also code examples would be nice, specially in Scala (I'm developing this project Scala).

Comment: Quadtrees can be a good starting point. What kind of surface do you want this to work on? Planar, spherical or do you need a full Earth model?

Comment: It can be spherical.
Besides quad trees I also thought of kd-trees and R trees. But all the examples I find are for finding the nearest point.

Comment: I think the tree-based ideas should be adaptable to this problem. Think in terms of splitting it into two pieces: 1. Find all points that might be within x of the target. 2. Check the actual distance for each of those points.

Comment: If you can find the nearest point, it should be easy then. Once you found it, check its distance from the origin: if it's bigger than the required range, you're finished. If it's smaller, add the point to the list and continue with the nearest point finding as if you hadn't found anything.

Comment: Yeah. It would be nice to be able to reach to a set of points that are within x of target and than filter those. Even if there are false positives it should be a lot faster than filtering thousands of nodes. I'm only afraid that there will be some false negatives.

Comment: For your problem, I believe that R-Tree is the best solution, since they are used (probably with some improvements) in comercial GIS (Geographic Information System).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself a few months late. Well I ended up using using KD-Tree to implement this. I based myself on this Java implementation: http://people.cs.vt.edu/~shaffer/Book/JAVA/progs/KDtree/

However I made some modifications to it (including porting it to Scala) and adapting it to my specific problem around Geocaches. The resulting code was the following:

```
/*
 * Based on
 * http://people.cs.vt.edu/~shaffer/Book/JAVA/progs/KDtree/
 * 
 * That code is made available as part of this textbook on Data Structures:
 * http://people.cs.vt.edu/~shaffer/Book/
 */
//A node for a KDTree
class KDNode[E] {
  private var key_value : Array[Double] = null   //key for this node
  def key = key_value                     
  def key_=(k : Array[Double]) { key_value = k } 

  private var element_value: E = _               //Element for this node
  def element = element_value
  def element_=(e : E) {element_value = e}

  private var left_value : KDNode[E] = null      //Pointer to left child
  def left = left_value
  def left_=(l : KDNode[E]) {left_value = l}

  private var right_value : KDNode[E] = null     //Pointer to right child
  def right = right_value
  def right_=(r : KDNode[E]) {right_value = r}
  /** Constructors */
  def this(k : Array[Double], value : E) = 
  {
    this()
    key = k
    element = value
  }
  def this(k : Array[Double], value : E, l : KDNode[E], r : KDNode[E]) = 
  {
    this(k,value)
    left = l
    right = r    
  }
  //Checks if it's a leaf
  def isLeaf : Boolean = 
  {
    return (left == null) && (right == null)
  }
}

//Trait for a basic Dictionary that will be used as basis for our KDTree
trait Dictionary[K,V] {
  def size: Int
  def insert(key: K, value: V)
  def remove(key: K): V
  def find(key: K): V
  def clear
  def isEmpty: Boolean
}

/**
 * A extended trait that defines that the key of the dictionary is an array of
 * doubles and defines the need of a method called regionSearchGeo (very
 * important for All Years 5 & 6 stats)
 */
trait GeoDictionary[E] extends Dictionary[Array[Double], E] {
  def regionSearchGeo(k: Array[Double], radius: Double) : List[E]
}

/**
 * Our implementation of a KDTree. It's based on the code provided in the
 * reference above, but had a few key areas modified for geographic searching.
 * For example, this KDtree is a 3D Tree. The keys are Latitude, Longitude and
 * the Year of the cache (that was also included to speed thins even further)
 */
class K3DGeoTree[E] extends GeoDictionary[E]{

  private var root : KDNode[E] = null
  private val D : Int = 3 // Only supporting 2D points in this implementation
  private var nodecount : Int = 0 // Number of nodes in the KD tree

  /**
   * Implementing everything that is required by the Dictionary trait
   * Some private auxiliary methods are also present
   */
  def clear() = { root = null }
  def isEmpty() : Boolean = { root == null }
  def size() : Int = { return nodecount }

  def insert(pt : Array[Double], value : E) = {
    root = inserthelp(root, pt, value, 0)
    nodecount=nodecount+1
  }
  def inserthelp(rt :  KDNode[E], key : Array[Double], value : E, level : Int)
                                 : KDNode[E] = {
    if (rt == null) return new KDNode[E](key, value)
    val rtkey : Array[Double] = rt.key
    if (rtkey(level) > key(level))
        rt.left = inserthelp(rt.left, key, value, (level+1)%D)
    else
        rt.right = inserthelp(rt.right, key, value, (level+1)%D)
    return rt
  }

  private def findmin(rt : KDNode[E], descrim : Int, level : Int): KDNode[E]= {
  var temp1 : KDNode[E] = null
  var temp2 : KDNode[E] = null
  var key1 : Array[Double] = null
  var key2 : Array[Double] = null
  if (rt == null) return null
  temp1 = findmin(rt.left, descrim, (level+1)%D)
  if (temp1 != null) key1 = temp1.key
  if (descrim != level) {
    temp2 = findmin(rt.right, descrim, (level+1)%D)
    if (temp2 != null) key2 = temp2.key
    if ((temp1 == null) || ((temp2 != null) && (key1(descrim) > key2(descrim))))
    temp1 = temp2
    key1 = key2
  } // Now, temp1 has the smaller value
  var rtkey : Array[Double] = rt.key
  if ((temp1 == null) || (key1(descrim) > rtkey(descrim)))
    return rt
  else
    return temp1
}

  def find(key : Array[Double]) : E = { return findhelp(root, key, 0) }

  private def findhelp(rt : KDNode[E], key : Array[Double], level : Int) : E ={
  if (rt == null) return null.asInstanceOf[E]
  val it : E = rt.element
  val itkey : Array[Double]= rt.key
  if ((itkey(0) == key(0)) && (itkey(1) == key(1)))
    return rt.element
  if (itkey(level) > key(level))
    return findhelp(rt.left, key, (level+1)%D)
  else
    return findhelp(rt.right, key, (level+1)%D)
}

  def remove(key : Array[Double]) : E = {
    val temp : E = findhelp(root, key, 0)   // First find it
    if (temp != null) {
            root = removehelp(root, key, 0) // Now remove it
            nodecount=nodecount-1
    }
    return temp
  }

  private def removehelp(rt : KDNode[E], key : Array[Double], level : Int)
                                             : KDNode[E] = {
      if (rt == null) return null
      val rtkey : Array[Double] = rt.key
      if (key(level) < rtkey(level))
        rt.left = removehelp(rt.left, key, (level+1)%D)
      else if (key(level) > rtkey(level))
        rt.right = removehelp(rt.right, key, (level+1)%D)
      else {  // Found it
      if (rt.right == null)
        if (rt.left == null) // Just drop element
         return null
      else { // Switch subtree to right
            rt.right = rt.left
            rt.left = null
      }
      val temp : KDNode[E] = findmin(rt.right, level, (level+1)%D)
      rt.right = removehelp(rt.right, temp.key, (level+1)%D)
      rt.element = temp.element
    }
    return rt
  }

  /**
   * Implementing the GeoDictionary trait
   */
  def regionSearchGeo(point: Array[Double], radius: Double) : List[E] = 
  {
    val pointGeo : GeoLocation = GeoLocation.fromDegrees(point(0), point(1))
    /**
     * Calculates a bounding rectangle that contains the circle with the given
     * radius. This will be explained later in the corresponding class
     */
    val boundingRect = pointGeo.boundingCoordinates(radius)  
    //Return the caches found
    return rsGeoHelp(root, point, radius, boundingRect, 0)
  }
  /**
   * Auxiliary region search function that does all the heavy work
   */
  private def rsGeoHelp(rt : KDNode[E], point : Array[Double], radius : Double,
                                                boundingRect : Tuple2[GeoLocation,GeoLocation],
                                                lev : Int): List[E] = {
  if (rt == null) return Nil
  val rtkey : Array[Double] = rt.key
  var found : List[E] = Nil
 //Checks if the current node is in the desired radius (and also the year)
  if (InCircleGeo(point, radius, rtkey))
          found = List(rt.element)
 //First Dimension is latitude
  if(lev % D == 0){
        if (rtkey(lev) >= boundingRect._1.degLat)
        found = found:::rsGeoHelp(rt.left, point, radius, boundingRect, (lev+1)%D)
        if (rtkey(lev) <= boundingRect._2.degLat)
        found = found:::rsGeoHelp(rt.right, point, radius, boundingRect, (lev+1)%D)
  }
 //Second Dimension is Longitude
  else if(lev % D == 1){
        if (rtkey(lev) >= boundingRect._1.degLon)
        found = found:::rsGeoHelp(rt.left, point, radius, boundingRect, (lev+1)%D)
        if (rtkey(lev) <= boundingRect._2.degLon)
    found = found:::rsGeoHelp(rt.right, point, radius, boundingRect, (lev+1)%D)
  }
 //Third and last dimension is the year
  else{
    found = found:::rsGeoHelp(rt.left, point, radius, boundingRect, (lev+1)%D)
        if (rtkey(lev) <= point(lev))
        found = found:::rsGeoHelp(rt.right, point, radius, boundingRect, (lev+1)%D)
  }
  //Return the found nodes (in our case it will be caches)
  return found
  }
  private def InCircleGeo(point : Array[Double], radius : Double,
                                                  coord : Array[Double]) : Boolean = {
  //Creates a GeoLocation object for each point
  val pointGeo : GeoLocation = GeoLocation.fromDegrees(point(0), point(1))
  val coordGeo : GeoLocation = GeoLocation.fromDegrees(coord(0), coord(1))
  /**
   * If the year is smaller than the query point and the distance is within
   * radius return true. Else it's false.
   */
  return (coord(0) != point(0) && coord(1) != point(1) && coord(2) <= point(2)
         && pointGeo.distanceTo(coordGeo) < radius)
  }
}

/**
 * This class encapsulates a series of utility methods to deal with geographic
 * coordinates. It was based on the information in the link below that gives
 * a very good insight about how to do math with geographic coordinates and
 * also provides some Java samples that we used as an inspiration for this
 * class.
 * Link: http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates
 */
//Companion object of Class GeoLocation to define static methods and variables
object GeoLocation {
  //Min maxs in terms of Latitude and Longitude accross the globe
  private val MIN_LAT : Double = math.toRadians(-90)  // -PI/2
  private val MAX_LAT : Double = math.toRadians(90)   //  PI/2
  private val MIN_LON : Double = math.toRadians(-180) // -PI
  private val MAX_LON : Double = math.toRadians(180)  //  PI
  /**
   * Earth radius. This value is the most used but there are others that may
   * give slightly different results.
   */
  private val RADIUS : Double = 6372.8

  /**
   * A factory method that creates a GeoLocation object from given latitude and
   * longitude in degrees
   */
  def fromDegrees(latitude : Double, longitude : Double) : GeoLocation = {
    val result : GeoLocation = new GeoLocation()
        result.radLat = math.toRadians(latitude)
        result.radLon = math.toRadians(longitude)
        result.degLat = latitude
        result.degLon = longitude
        result.checkBounds
        return result
  }

  /**
   * A factory method that creates a GeoLocation object from given latitude and
   * longitude in radians
   */
  def fromRadians(latitude : Double, longitude : Double) : GeoLocation = {
        val result : GeoLocation = new GeoLocation()
        result.radLat = latitude
        result.radLon = longitude
        result.degLat = math.toDegrees(latitude)
        result.degLon = math.toDegrees(longitude)
        result.checkBounds
        return result
  }
}
/**
 * The GeoLocation class itself. The constructor is private use the factory
 * methods above.
 */
class GeoLocation private{

  /**
   * Getters and Setters implemented as properties with syntactic sugar
   * This properties  contain the latitude and longitude in degrees and radians
   */
  private var radLat_value : Double = _
  def radLat = radLat_value                    
  private def radLat_=(k : Double) { radLat_value = k } 

  private var radLon_value : Double = _
  def radLon = radLon_value                    
  private def radLon_=(k : Double) { radLon_value = k } 

  private var degLat_value : Double = _
  def degLat = degLat_value                    
  private def degLat_=(k : Double) { degLat_value = k } 

  private var degLon_value : Double = _
  def degLon = degLon_value                    
  private def degLon_=(k : Double) { degLon_value = k } 

  /**
   * Check if the vales are valid considering the MIN and MAX for latitude and
   * longitude.
   */
  private def checkBounds = {
        if (radLat < GeoLocation.MIN_LAT || radLat > GeoLocation.MAX_LAT ||
                radLon < GeoLocation.MIN_LON || radLon > GeoLocation.MAX_LON)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException()
  }

  /**
   * Function to calculate the distance between this GeoLocation and the given
   * GeoLocation.
   * 
   * Check the reference above and
   * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
   * for more information.
   */
  def distanceTo(location : GeoLocation) : Double = {
        return math.acos(math.sin(radLat) * math.sin(location.radLat) +
                   math.cos(radLat) * math.cos(location.radLat) *
                   math.cos(radLon - location.radLon)) * GeoLocation.RADIUS
  }

  /**
   * This method is very important for the search made in the K3DTree.
   * It allows us to make a bouding rectangle with the given distance/radius
   * that is geometrically correct. Check the reference above to learn more
   * about the math involved.
   */
  def boundingCoordinates(distance : Double)
        : Tuple2[GeoLocation, GeoLocation] = {
    if (distance < 0d) throw new IllegalArgumentException()
        // Angular distance in radians on a great circle
        val radDist : Double = distance / GeoLocation.RADIUS

        //Initialize local variables to check for poles
        var minLat : Double = radLat - radDist
        var maxLat : Double = radLat + radDist

        var minLon : Double = 0
        var maxLon : Double = 0

        //Normal case
        if (minLat > GeoLocation.MIN_LAT && maxLat < GeoLocation.MAX_LAT) {
                val deltaLon : Double = math.asin(math.sin(radDist) / math.cos(radLat))
                        minLon = radLon - deltaLon
                if (minLon < GeoLocation.MIN_LON) minLon += 2d * math.Pi
                        maxLon = radLon + deltaLon
                if (maxLon > GeoLocation.MAX_LON) maxLon -= 2d * math.Pi
        }
    //Special case in which a pole is within the distance
        else{
                        minLat = math.max(minLat, GeoLocation.MIN_LAT)
                        maxLat = math.min(maxLat, GeoLocation.MAX_LAT)
                        minLon = GeoLocation.MIN_LON
                        maxLon = GeoLocation.MAX_LON
                }       
    /**
     * Each of the bounding points (one in the south-west, bottom-left,
     * and other in the north-east, top-right)
     */
    val swPoint : GeoLocation = GeoLocation.fromRadians(minLat, minLon)
    val nePoint : GeoLocation = GeoLocation.fromRadians(maxLat, maxLon) 
    //Return the tuple with the two points
    return (swPoint, nePoint)
  }
}
```

The whole code is documented so I hope this helps someone with a similar problem. In this specific problem I had to deal with years besides latitude and longitude, so I added an extra dimension. But for a more general geographic problem it's even easier to do it with only two dimensions (one for latitude and one for longitude).

Answer (score 3):

For this problem I'd use a java library (this is possible in Scala).
Calculating distances on earth is much more difficult than you think. The earth is not a pefect sphere for example.
The main library for doing 'geo stuff' in java is JTS: http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html
You can also take a look at Geotools or maybe even a GIS-database like PostGIS (built on Postgresql), but that might be overkill for your project